# Main class not found in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been trying to use a remote Git repository in NetBeans for the first time in a program rather than a library. However, each time I click run, all the class files in build/classes are deleted. This is the oddest thing that has ever happened to me in NetBeans, and I have never seen anything like it any where.

Does anyone know what is going on?

**Update:** My problem is now recurring, in a slightly different way. The versions of the classes that were there before I pushed the code to the remote repository are now being substituted. Both in my original problem and now, the class files ended up in a folder beginning with `s` and ending with a short number. How can I fix this problem permanently, without temporary fixes such as clearing the cache?

Comment: Are the .class files present before you click run? As with all Netbeans wierdness, have you tried clearing the [cache](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)?

Comment: If I click Clean and Build before clicking Run, yes, they are there before I click run. I decompiled them, and they are generated from my code. No, I have not tried clearing the cache, and I will after I post this comment. Should Netbeans have a menu item to clear the cache?

Comment: Ding! I cleared the cache, and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @andy256 if you add that as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @andy256 +1 for the astute observation. Add your observation as an answer, so we can upvote and OP can accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the .class files present before you click run?

As with all Netbeans wierdness, have you tried clearing the [cache](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)?

Comment: I now have another recurring instance of the problem. Can I fix this permanently without having to clear the cache each time?

Comment: I suspect that this a git issue, rather than Netbeans; I cannot be of more help. How about you post a new problem, and tag it as a git question.